# Audio not working on Chromebook

Tags: sound, chromebook

I am using Samsung Chromebook 2(winky). I successfully installed Ubuntu via modified BIOS. And everything is working fine except the audio (chipset chtmax98090).

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  I suggest you add a few more details like the version of Ubuntu that you are using.  Also, maybe give an example of the solutions/sites you have tried.

Comment: Never mind I found the solution

Comment: Hey @Asrith, since this is a Q&A site and answers/solutions are expected to be posted in answer section. I have redacted solution part from your question and added as an answer. But if you wish to post that, ping me in comments using `@Kulfy`. I'll delete my answer and upvote yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install ucm2's latest version from Debian testing site. And the audio is working perfectly fine. Tested on Samsung Chromebook 2 (winky), chtmax98090, Ubuntu 20.10